# Razor Url.Action adding site folder path into Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an MVC project that lives on server in *`/root/folder1/`*, and a domain name pointing there.
So the url, *`www.site.com/Home`* is working fine.

However, all my `@Html.ActionLinks` and `@Url.Action`, etc. are rendering as *`www.site.com/folder1/Home`*

The links still work, but it is ugly, and I don't want the folder name to be known.

Anyone know why it's doing this and how to stop it?

Comment: add quotes from code and improve formatting

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: @asymptoticFault, just the standard out-of-the-box Default Route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.  @dzada, I'll work on it.  First question ever.

Comment: @user1160006 could you please post a snippet of your ActionLink???

Answer (score 1):

You should be using something like this for your `ActionLinks`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName") 'NOTE YOU DO NOT NEED TO INCLUDE THE Controller part of the controller name. So for say AdminController you could simply set the controllerName in the ActionLink to `Admin`
```

You can also setup your `ActionLinks` like the below if you have to pass an `Id` or other value to the controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", New With {.YourVariableName = "SomeValue"})
```

If you need to specify and HTML attribute for the control being rendered you can set those with one more overload.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", New With {.YourVariableName = "SomeValue"}, New With {.htmlAttributeName = ""})
```

If you need to Specify the `HTML attribute` without a need to pass a value to the controller you can simply replace `New With`{.YourVariableName = "SomeValue"}`with`Nothing`

Hope this works or at least points you in the right direction. A fresh MVC project out of the box has a `Controllers` folder. Which means server path looks something like `root/controllerFolder/controller/action` using the above works fine for me and only produces Url's that follow the standard `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Say I have a need to call an Edit Action inside the AdminController which needs an `ID` so it knows what record I want to edit and I also want to add a class to this button so I can style it or anything else. I would do this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Admin", NEW WITH {.ID = @currItem.Id}, NEW WITH{.Class = "MyButtonClass"})
```

The URL that is generated will look like this

```
    www.mysite.com/Admin/Edit/2
```

maybe this is a little more than you needed but your question appears to actually follow the standard `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Just in-case I am missing something I figured I would try to at least point you in the right direction.